# knockout css dynamic binding

Tags: css, binding, knockout.js

I am working on a little project with knockout where i have to simulate the answer to asome questions.
I dynamically build 3 buttons and when i click one i compare the text on it with the correct answer and if it's correct it should become green.., if it's not correct it should become red and the right one should become green.. 
I was trying to use the binding to css property of knockout, but it seems that the property is not correctly refreshed, even if the computed associated with the css changes
The html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: chosenQuestionAnswers">
  <li>
    <button data-bind="text: answerText, css: $root.answerStatus(), click: $root.selectButton"></button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The ko part:

```
 selectedAnswer: ko.observable(),
 isAnswerCorrect: ko.observable(),

selectButton: function (value) {    my.AppViewModel.isAnswerCorrect(my.AppViewModel.checkIfCorrectAnswer(value.answerText));
 },

checkIfCorrectAnswer: function (value) {
return (value == my.AppViewModel.chosenQuestionCorrectAnswer());
  },

my.AppViewModel.answerStatus = ko.computed(function () {
var exit = this.isAnswerCorrect() == true ? "highlightRight" : "highlightWrong";
console.log(this.isAnswerCorrect());
console.log(exit);
return exit;
 }, my.AppViewModel);
```

The console.log shows the correct value of the var exit... but the css of the button does not change...

Any idea why?..

Thanks.... I.

Comment: can you please put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mimi/7SbpE/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're referencing an old version of KO (2.1), the latest as of today is version is 2.2.1.  Your fiddle works when referencing the new version @ http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js.  Here's a fork: http://jsfiddle.net/drdamour/xe2M5/

The dynamic css binding (how you're using it) was only added in 2.2 see http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/

stack won't let me submit without some code so...here some worthless code:

```
var x = {a:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

css classes are part of the view, try to keep them out of the ViewModel, it should focus on business logic.

I would do something like

http://jsfiddle.net/hLXbq/

HTML

```
<button data-bind="css: { valid: valid, invalid: invalid }, click: toggle">Toggle</button>
```

JS

```
ViewModel = function () {
    this.valid = ko.observable(false);
    this.invalid = ko.computed(function () {
        return !this.valid();
    }, this);
};
```

Comment: i was trying with this, http://jsfiddle.net/mimi/7SbpE/2/... your modification works correctly in another example, but i cannot make it work on this one.. ..

Comment: @Ivan_nn2 you've got an old KO reference, the feature you're using isn't available in that one.

Comment: Chris is right, css could only be bound to a object literal in that version. However, i still think its a good practice to keep view dependendies out of the ViewModel

Comment: @Anders, I agree with you, but it seems like the Knockout docs encourage exactly this type of code. See the "dynamic classes" section on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Comment: Yes, but profitStatus could be a domain term so you could get away with it in that example, but stil I think its more clean to have these strings in the view. It does introduce a computed to invert the value though.

Comment: @VladMagdalin ...yes that is the reason why i wrote the code in that way.. .causei saw an example on ko tutorial

Comment: @Anders... thank you, I will try to follow your advice and decoupled the 2 things...

Comment: i think it's perfectly valid to have a class description in the VM.  It describes what the VM is, and then to use css to decorate those instances seems natural.  This is similar to ODF/XHTML/microformats.  The v in VM is view...otherwise it'd just be M